# openCV: How to use getPerspectiveTransform

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image represented by a matrix of size `n * n`

I've created a transform matrix

```
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(...)
```

And I can transform the image with the shape defined in `M` using

```
cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, image_shape)
```

According to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform), I should be able to multiply the matrix with a point and get the new location of that point, after the transformation. I tried that:

```
point = [100, 100, 0]
x, y, z = M.dot(point)
```

But I got the wrong results. (In this case [112.5    12.5    0])

What am I doing wrong?

---

For more clarity, here's what I'm doing:

I have this image, with the lines and the square on different layers

[image: before warp]

I warp the lines and get this:

[image: warped lines]

And now I want to get the coordinates for putting the square like this:

[image: expected]

What I have is the warp matrix I used for the lines, and the coordinates of the square in the first picture

---

Note: one option is to create an image with a single dot, just warp it with the first method and find the non-zero cells in the new image. I'm looking for something more idiomatic than that, hopefully

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opencv homography to find global xy coordinates from pixel xy coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578876/opencv-homography-to-find-global-xy-coordinates-from-pixel-xy-coordinates)

Comment: If you see the link you are giving, it says the last element of `point` should be 1, and you use 0!!...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The last point of a homogeneous coordinate should never be 0 unless it is specifically referencing a *point at infinity*. For your purposes, it should be `1`. You should also scale the transformed pixels `x` and `y` by the last value `z`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578876/opencv-homography-to-find-global-xy-coordinates-from-pixel-xy-coordinates) for an in-depth explanation.

For a single point:

```
point = np.array([100, 100])
homg_point = [point[0], point[1], 1] # homogeneous coords
transf_homg_point = M.dot(homg_point) # transform
transf_homg_point /= transf_homg_point[2] # scale
transf_point = transf_homg_point[:2] # remove Cartesian coords
```

For multiple points (with the standard way that OpenCV writes points):

```
points = np.array([[[100, 100]], [[150,100]], [[150,150]], [[150,100]]])
homg_points = np.array([[x, y, 1] for [[x, y]] in points]).T
transf_homg_points = M.dot(homg_points)
transf_homg_points /= transf_homg_points[2]
transf_points = np.array([[[x,y]] for [x, y] in transf_homg_points[:2].T])
```

A minimal example using points grabbed from an OpenCV function:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

# generate random noise image, draw a white box
img = np.random.rand(512,512,3)
img[128:384, 64:196] = [1,1,1]

# create a Euclidean transformation which rotates by 30 deg + translates by (100,100)
theta = 30*np.pi/180
H = np.array([
    [ np.cos(theta),np.sin(theta),100.],
    [-np.sin(theta),np.cos(theta),100.],
    [0.,0.,1.]])

# find the white box
bin_img = cv2.inRange(img, np.ones(3), np.ones(3))
contour_points = cv2.findContours(bin_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1][0]

# transform the location of the box
homg_points = np.array([[x, y, 1] for [[x, y]] in contour_points]).T
transf_homg_points = H.dot(homg_points)
transf_homg_points /= transf_homg_points[2]
transf_rect = np.array([[[x,y]] for [x, y] in transf_homg_points[:2].T], dtype=np.int32)

# draw the transformed box as a green outline
cv2.polylines(img, [transf_rect], isClosed=True, color=[0,1,0], thickness=2)
```

Yielding an image with random noise, a white box, and a green outline which shows the transformation applied to the box contours.

[image: Transformed contour]