# Python opencv homography - How can I get the new x and y position of the object?

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I am trying to use homography for court detection. And I have detected an object (a player) in the original image and I am now trying to figure out what are it's new coordinates on the wrapped image.

(I am trying to create a minimap system)

**I want to figure out new x and y coordinates of the player on the wrapped image**

This is my program so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#player coordinates - multiple players
x_coords = []
y_coords = []

print(x_coords)
print(y_coords)


#basketball court, size-1830, 910
pts_src = np.array([
    [394, 412], # top left corner
    [0, 500],
    [0, 670],     
    [910, 770],
    [1830, 720],     
    [1830,545],
    [1540, 450]      # top right corner
])

#minimap, size-500,300 
pts_dst = np.array([
    [0, 0],         # top left corner
    [0, 275],
    [25, 300],      
    [250, 300],
    [475, 300],
    [500, 275],     
    [500, 0]       # top right corner
])

#find homography
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)


img_src2 = cv2.imread('basketball_court.png')
img_out = cv2.warpPerspective(img_src2, h, (img_dst.shape[1], img_dst.shape[0]))

cv2.imshow("Warped", img_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)`
```

I have tried using this for help but just can't figure out what to do: [Opencv homography to find global xy coordinates from pixel xy coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578876/opencv-homography-to-find-global-xy-coordinates-from-pixel-xy-coordinates)

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#convertpointsfromhomogeneous

Comment: The homography can be used to project individual points as well as an image.

Comment: You may have to invert the homography matrix for projecting from the input to the output.

Comment: Can you please edit your post, and the images? What is `img_dst`? You are using `img_dst` in your code, but you are not reading it... Can you please post a code sample we can execute? It looks like your 7 points doesn't form a valid transformation - I recommend you to select set of 4 source and destination points that forms a rectangle and make sure the order is correct. After that, you can probably use `cv2.transform(np.array([pts_src], np.float32), h)[0]` (but I am not sure).

Comment: The points represent part of an image with the court on (the lines)

Comment: And the program does transform successfully, I only want to figure out how to find the new x, y coordinates of a specific part of the previous image

Comment: If the question is not good enough, don't expect it to be answered. Believe me that I tried to solve it but I gave up... When asking a question, try not to think only about your current specific problem, try to also think about the person how tries to answer, and about other users how may find it useful in the future. Note: In case you want to contact me, start the comment with @Rotem.